# How to access a Session variable set in Meteor.isCordova from Meteor.isCLient?

Tags: cordova, meteor

```
if (Meteor.isCordova){
    Session.set('givenUser',msgPayloadStr);
    console.log(Session.get('givenUser')); // printed in Cordova console (chrome inspect)
}

if (Meteor.isClient){
   window.setInterval(function(){
       if (!Meteor.isCordova){console.log(Session.get('givenUser'));}
   },1000);
}
```

Nothing is printed client-side (only undefined, and so on).

Comment: why are you mixing reactivevar and session? givenUser isn't defined in your example. Try printing Session.get('givenUser')

Comment: it was a typo. edited the answer

Comment: Try using meteor.startup